# Actionscript 3, how to use hitTestObject between two or more classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am trying to create a little interactive drag and drop program that will check if the drop location is the fishBowl class object and either places the dragged object in the fishBowl object or will jump back to the original created location if it does not hit the fishBowl object.

The problem that I have been having is that the if statement does not recognize the drop location as an object of a class and after two days of coding different ways I can not get it to work.

This is my J_Objects class where the child classes inherent from:

```
package classes {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class J_Objects extends Sprite {
        private var xSpeed:int = 0;
        private var ySpeed:int = 2;
        private var topPadding:int = 250;
        private var drag:Boolean = false;
        private var tempSpeedX:int = xSpeed;
        private var tempSpeedY:int = ySpeed;


        public function J_Objects(_x:int, _y:int) {
            // constructor code
            this.x = _x;
            this.y = _y;
            this.buttonMode = true; //add hand cursor on mouse hover
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
        }

        public function move():void {
            if (this.xSpeed <= -1) {
                    this.scaleX = -1;
                }
                else if (this.xSpeed >= 1) {
                    this.scaleX = 1;
                }
            //Check if at the left or right and change direction if so
            if ((this.x - this.width/2 <= 0) || (this.x + this.width/2 >= stage.stageWidth)) {
                this.xSpeed *= -1;
                //this.scaleX *= -1;


            }//Also check if that top or bottom and if so change direction
            else if ((this.y - this.topPadding - this.height/2 <= 0) ||  (this.y + this.height/2 >= stage.stageHeight)) {
            this.ySpeed *= -1;
            }
            this.x += this.xSpeed;
            this.y += this.ySpeed;
            }

            /* Drag and Drop
            Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
            */
            public function clickToDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.startDrag();
                pickedUp();
                xSpeed = 0;
                ySpeed = 0;

                //var dragEvent:Event = new Event('DRAG_OBJECT', true );
                //this.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);

            }

            public function releaseToDrop(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.stopDrag();

                //fishBowl.object();
                if (evt.currentTarget.hitTestObject(evt.target.name == "fishBowl")) {
                    trace("Fishbowl got hit");
                }
                else {
                    xSpeed = tempSpeedX;
                    ySpeed = tempSpeedY;
                    putDown();
                    trace("Dropped objects was: ", this.name);
                }
                /*if (evt.target.hitTestObject(evt.target.name) == fishBowl) {
                    trace("Fishbowl got hit");
                }
                else {
                    xSpeed = tempSpeedX;
                    ySpeed = tempSpeedY;
                    putDown();
                    trace("Dropped objects was: ", this.name);
                }*/


            }

            public function pickedUp():void {
                //var tempX:int = 0;
                //var tempY:int = 0;
                //tempX = this.x;
                //tempY = this.y;
                //this.x = 
            }

            public function putDown():void {
                //pickedUp();
                //this.x = tempX;
                //this.y = tempY;
            }


    }

}
```

I have tried several different ways in the if statement but I get the: can not change Boolean to class, can not access static variable etc etc.

These are the code for the child objects:

```
package classes {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;



    public class J_GoldFish extends J_Objects {
        var tempX:int = 0;
        var tempY:int = 0;


        public function J_GoldFish(_x:int, _y:int) {
            // constructor code
            super(_x, _y);
            tempX = _x;
            tempY = _y;
        }

        override public function putDown():void {
            this.x = tempX;
            this.y = tempY;
        }
    }

}

package classes {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;



    public class J_BlueFish extends J_Objects {
        var tempX:int = 0;
        var tempY:int = 0;

        public function J_BlueFish(_x:int, _y:int) {
            // constructor code
            super(_x, _y);
            tempX = _x;
            tempY = _y;
        }

        override public function putDown():void {
            this.x = tempX;
            this.y = tempY;
        }
    }

}


package classes {

    import flash.display.Sprite;



    public class J_FishBowl extends Sprite {



        public function J_FishBowl(_x:int, _y:int) {
            // constructor code
            this.x = _x;
            this.y = _y;
        }
    }

}
```

And then the main class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import classes.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var goldFish:J_GoldFish;
        private var blueFish:J_BlueFish;
        private var bird:J_Bird;
        private var fishBowl:J_FishBowl;
        private var pass:String = "";


        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
            this.goldFish = new J_GoldFish(146.80, 372.75);
            this.blueFish = new J_BlueFish(59.95, 335.05);
            this.bird = new J_Bird(497.35, 48.45);
            this.fishBowl = new J_FishBowl(269.30, 319.50);
            this.fishBowl.name = "fishBowl";
            this.goldFish.name = "goldFish";
            this.blueFish.name = "blueFish";
            this.bird.name = "bird";
            addChild(this.fishBowl);
            addChild(this.goldFish);
            addChild(this.blueFish);
            addChild(this.bird);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
            //this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, sendObject);
            //stage.addEventListener('DRAG_OBJECT', stopAnimate);

        private function animate(evt:Event):void {
        //make the fish animate (move)
        this.goldFish.move();
        this.blueFish.move();
        this.bird.move();

        }

        private function stopAnimate(evt:Event):void {
            //var target:J_Objects = (evt.target as J_Objects); //definde the target incase I want to change properties         
            //stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is actually twofold.

In the following line of code:

`if (evt.currentTarget.hitTestObject(evt.target.name == "fishBowl"))`

Your parentheses are in the wrong place, and therefore, you're attempting to call the method `hitTestObject` on the boolean derived from evaluating `evt.target.name == "fishBowl"`

In order to get rid of your error, you'd have to change it to something like:

`if (evt.currentTarget.hitTestObject(evt.target))`

This would not solve you *main* problem, however, which is the fact that the `target` (and, depending on what sort of display objects are contained within the target, `currentTarget`) of `evt` will be the object that was dropped as it is the object that has dispatched the MOUSE_UP event.

Since you are attempting to find the object on which the dropped object has been placed, you'll want to look at the `dropTarget` property.

Here is the corrected `releaseToDrop` function:

```
public function releaseToDrop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stopDrag();

    if (this.dropTarget && this.dropTarget.name == "fishBowl")
    {
        trace("Fishbowl got hit");
    }
    else 
    {
        xSpeed = tempSpeedX;
        ySpeed = tempSpeedY;
        putDown();
        trace("Dropped objects was: ", this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I will try this straight away! You don't know how many hours and days of trial and error this has been for me now! :D

Comment: right it works as in it compiles and seems to be functioning without any major issues but it does not seem to recognize the fishBowl object as an object at all. I made a hover over object function to test this, and the two fish and the bird get registered but when I hover over the fishBowl object, nothing happens... any ideas? Tnx

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening on your end. I actually grabbed all of your code and created a project to test it. With the edited `releaseToDrop` method, I was able to get it to trace out "Fishbowl got hit" when I dropped a fish onto the bowl.

Is it possible that you are modifying the `hitArea` of the fishbowl at any point in your code?

Comment: No could not find any hitArea code in there. I have replaced my releaseToDrop if statement condition with the one you suggested and do not have the if (evt.currentTarget.hitTestObject(evt.target)) part anymore is this right? Really not sure why it does not recognize my fishBowl object.

Comment: You may want to try debugging (breakpoints/trace statements) to find out what the `dropTarget` property is when you do drop an object onto what you expect to be a fishBowl.

Comment: Right, well I did think about that and the dropTarget name = instance8 when it is set to fishBowl in the main method. Not sure why it is not changing the name as it is doing that for the other objects...

Comment: Additionally did I find out that the debugger is saying that the hitArea is null for all the objects I drop on and again I do not know why. Can this have something to do with the way my objects are drawn?

Comment: At this point, I think I'd have to see the entire application to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: Okay how would I get the app to you? I could mail it or give you a dropbox link, thanks again.